# MetaMask => Ledger Nano S

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

I sent 20 AION from MetaMask to my Ledger (Nano S)'s Ethereum 1 address, and it shows up when I paste in this address at https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info

But if I instead connect to Ledger at https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info, I am presented with a whole list of addresses to select from (actually five at a time) -- but none of them are my Ledger's Ethereum 1 address.

So 2 questions: 
1) Did I in fact send the 20 AION correctly?
2) What is connecting to Ledger via MEW all about, and how come my address does not show up in the list presented?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind -- all is fine now. I needed to select the top left radio button when connecting to Ledger LIVE -- as per https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005200009-How-to-use-MyEtherWallet-with-Ledger.

The point of confusion is that that radio button does not mention Ledger at ALL -- so of course why should I select it (unless of course I happen to read the instructions)?

(I contacted Ledger support advising them to tell MEW to update their GUI in this regard.)